# Ajaxify's History and Bookmarking not working on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, ajax, hashchange, browser-state

Ajaxify is quite a well known jQuery plugin.  But I just used Chrome and try this page:

http://max.jsrhost.com/ajaxify/demo.php

for the New v2 features: History & Bookmarking.  When I click on Link 1, 2, and 3, and click the back button on Chrome, the content is not refreshed.  So for now, this feature doesn't work on Chrome?  Is it because the newest Chrome doesn't work well with it, but previous version of Chrome did?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont have the complete answer, but I can give you a start, as I am attempting to make it work as we speak..

The newest jquery.history.js file does work in chrome:

http://www.serpere.info/jquery-history-plugin/samples/ajax/

and, not to be putting down on ajaxify, I have used it for years, but I sometimes think it has been a bit of a crutch for me, not really learning the simplicity of ajax myself since 'Max' did such a sweet job with ajaxify itself.

I am currently just utilizing that little ajax demo from the history.js site itself, for my needs, its working just fine..but I am still trying to get ajaxify back..

It really seems simple, ajaxify is using the old history file, and a history.fixed.js file, and the both use the old style of historyInit() instead of the new history.init(), I spent a few minutes, ok hours, trying to get it to work, but could not, I am gonna give it a try again, but have just put in a email to 'Max' from ajaxify per his site:

http://max.jsrhost.com

but it didnt seem to send..

I will keep you posted!

(hats off to stackoverflow!! thank you thank you thank you for being you!!)